# The requested resource [/jenkins] is not available

Tags: jenkins, tomcat, jenkins-plugins, devops, tomcat10

I installed JDK 11.0 and then installed Tomcat 10.0 and have set all Environment variables and placed jenkins.war file also. Now, localhost:8080 is running fine but localhost:8080/jenkins is not working.

It gives error:

HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/jenkins] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/10.0.21

Can anyone help?

Comment: https://issues.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-64548. Use tomcat 9

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
root@jenkins ~]# vim /usr/local/tomcat/conf/context.xml
```

add this

```
<Context>
.....
    <Loader jakartaConverter="TOMCAT" />
</Context>
```

then in tomcat/bin

```
./shutdown.sh
./startup.sh
```

Comment: Can you please add a brief explanation of why this works?